# IntellijIdea console latency

Tags: java, intellij-idea, output

I have the following code. Main thread starts another thread. After 7 seconds the main thread interrupts another thread.

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
                {
                    System.out.println("Sleeping #" + i);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println("Interrupted");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(7000);
            t.interrupt();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

I expected to get such output:

```
Sleeping #0
Sleeping #1
Interrupted
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.company.Main$1.run(Main.java:16)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Sleeping #2
Sleeping #3
... and so on
```

But what I get is:

```
Sleeping #0
Sleeping #1
Interrupted
Sleeping #2
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.company.Main$1.run(Main.java:16)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Sleeping #3
... and so on
```

It first prints "`Interrupted`". Then the output from the next iteration "`Sleeping #2`", and then it prints stack trace. Why does it happen? It seems there is latency for printing stack trace. Is it IntelliJ Idea console related problem? Because when I run the program in a native console, it works well.

Comment: `printStacktrace` outputs to stderr rather than stdout. The console doesn't really offer any guarantees about how it's going to interleave them.

Comment: @pvg, so? If it is the reason, then why it works well when running in a console?

Comment: What do you mean 'so'? There are two different streams. How one terminal or another chooses to interleave them is implementation dependent. If you want to get strictly sequential output, output to the same stream.

Comment: @pvg, oh, thanks. I got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.out.println` outputs to `stdout` while `Throwable.printStackTrace` outputs to `stderr`. A terminal implementation may buffer each independently and the way the outputs of each stream will be interleaved is not well-defined.

If you want to ensure output from a given thread is displayed strictly sequentially, direct all output to the same stream. In your case, you can either change your printlns to use `System.err` or use `Throwable.printStackTrace(System.out)`